# SSIS error loading package in VS 2012 with TFS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, tfs, ssis

I am receiving the following error when trying to execute an SSIS package using Visual Studio 2012:

> Error 39  Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The
>   package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from
>   XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this
>   problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error
>   information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML
>   fails.   ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The package
>   failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No
>   further detailed error information can be specified for this problem
>   because no Events object was passed where detailed error information
>   can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackagePersist100.LoadPackageFromXML(Object
>   vSource, Boolean vbSourceIsLocation, IDTSEvents100 pEvents)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.LoadFromXML(String packageXml,
>   IDTSEvents events)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.LoadFromXML(String
>   packageXml, IDTSEvents events)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.LoadPackage(IProjectStorage
>   storage, Package package, String streamName, IDTSEvents events)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Load(IDTSEvents events)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.get_Package()     at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow
>   outputWindow)     at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow
>   outputWindow)
>
> 0 0

The package is stored in TFS and I can open the package/solution without any errors.  I just get the error when i try to excecute the package or any step in the package.

I created a new package on my machine (64 bit) and it worked fine.  I'm just having trouble running the package when opening from TFS.

thanks
Scott

Comment: While you might be using TFS for your source repository, do you actually have the package(s) on your machine? Behind the scenes, when you hit F5 to run a package in SSDT/BIDS/VS, with the 2012 release and the project deployment model, it first compiles the packages, connection managers and project parameters into a .ispac file (zip) and then performs operations against the .ispac itself to run packages. If someone's checked in the `Development\bin\project.ispac` things might go south with the build/run process if it doesn't get checked out automagically

Comment: billinkc, 

i created a workspace on my local c: drive and then extracted the entire folder.  I then opened the solution in VS 2012 and checked out the package.  This is where I get the error.

However, If i create a brand new ssis project on my machine in VS 2012 and add this package to the project, it works fine.  I do have multiple version of Visual Studio on my machine (2008/2010/2012), so not sure if there is a version conflict when I open the package from TFS.

Comment: I suspect the root problem is that you are using the wrong Visual Studio version to go with your SSIS packages. VS 2005 -> SQL Server 2005. VS 2008 -> SQL Server 2008/2008 R2. VS 2010 -> SQL Server 2008/2008 R2 AND SQL Server 2012. VS 2012 -> SQL Server 2012 and eventually SQL Server 2014.

Comment: thanks billinkc, is there a way to tell visual studio what version of SQL to use?

Comment: billinkc, i also was able to run the package using the SQL Server 2012 SSIS Execute Package Utility.  It just fails when running from the Visual Studio 2012 IDE??  Very frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a very similar situation by changing the SQL Server sdk version that my solution was pointing.

I had SQL Server Express 2008 installed, and was using VS 2012 with BI Tools 2012. So, my solution was referencing the assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll version 10. For my case, the correct was the version 12.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to open an SSIS package which used a component which I did not have installed. In my case, it was the "Azure Feature Pack".

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors on a Win64, VS2013, SQL2012 system. The SSIS package did not load correctly.
Identify: I created a local copy of the whole package, and narrowed the problem with reduction to a single sub-package.
Reason: different date format.
Solution: I had to change the Windows date format to UK (source of the package), and since then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the reference libraries to the Program Files directly as well. 
I saw that in the (x86) path, the files were there, but not in the 64-bit folder of Program Files. I'm using **Visual Studio 2010**.

```
1 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Connections

2 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Connections
```

The referenced DLL was found in location 1, but not in 2.
I closed Visual Studio, copied the DLL over to path 2, and opened VS again. The package just worked like normal.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a very similar situation by changing the TargetServerVersion in the project general configuration properties. I use Visual Studio 2015. By default SQL Server vNext was selected, whereas I have SQL Server 2012 installed.